# Insert and Update table row based on date

Tags: mysql, vb.net

before i'll insert TIMEOUT in the database, 
i want to update its corresponding time-in

```
      where timeIN.id = timeOUT.id
```

One successful scenario of merge is:

```
      when date.timeIN = date.timeOUT   (just like UID = 3)
```

Second scenario is i'm having trouble

```
      when date.timeIN != date.timeOUt  ( i want to merge UID = 1 and UID = 2)
```

I cannot use the date as a basis of my query because they are not
equal. Is it possible to query when date.timeIN has been added 1 day?

example:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UID |    EID   |       date            |     IN      |    OUT    |  CLASS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |   X001   |  2013-06-03 18:00:00  |   6:00 PM   |           |   IN
|  2  |   X001   |  2013-07-03 05:58:00  |             |  5:58 AM  |   OUT
|  3  |   X002   |  2013-06-03 07:30:00  |   7:30 AM   |  6:00 PM  |
```

What is the algorithm for this..or could you give me a hint on how it will be done. I'm using vb.net.

EDIT: 
I just want to update the timeout of the first row using the timeout value in the second row ? how do i do this in vb and mysql?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UID |    EID   |       date            |     IN      |    OUT    |  CLASS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |   X001   |  2013-06-03 18:00:00  |   6:00 PM   |  5:58 AM  |
```

Comment: Given your example, what are your desired results?  I'm not completely sure I understand.

Comment: merge UID=1 and UID=2

Comment: And that would result it what exactly?  Which UID, which date, which Class?  Please be a little more specific so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Given your edits, this should work using `GROUP BY` with `MIN()` to get UID and Date, and `MAX()` to get the IN and OUT columns:

```
select
  min(uid) uid,
  eid, 
  min(date) date, 
  max(`in`) `in`, 
  max(`out`) `out`
from yourtable
group by eid
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8f51c/1)

Selecting the MIN(date) may or may not be what you're looking for -- this presumes the MIN(date) would go with the corresponding IN record (IN comes before OUT).

Comment: sorry for not clarifying it..how it will be done when using update? I will just update the first row's timeout using the timeOut of the second row.

Comment: @rmm04 -- assuming you always have 1 in and 1 out for a each eid, then this will work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d25bf/1